# how to open a new modal upon clicking a button and display form input on the new modal window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new modal after clicking on a button on the first one and also displaying the input on the second modal from the form on the first modal. Can anyone please help? Here's my code:

```
    <!-- Modal Start -->
    <div class="modal fade text-center align-items-center" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="formModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="formModalTitle">Let's play the Madlibs Game!</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="close-text text-dark font-weight-bold float-right">x</a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body p-5">
                    <p class="modal-intro">Let's start, shall we? Fill out the form fields</p>
                    <!-- Form Start -->
                    <form id="madForm" name="madForm" action="javascript:write();">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="costume"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-grav"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="costume" name="costume" placeholder="A Custome" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="superhero"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="superhero" name="superhero" placeholder="A Superhero" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="food"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="food" name="food" placeholder="Any food" type="text" required="required"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="treats"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angellist"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="treats" name="treats" placeholder="Treats (candies, gummies, etc)"
                                    type="text" required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sweets"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="sweets" name="sweets" placeholder="Sweets (chocolates, etc)" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="place"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="park" name="park" placeholder="A spot in the park" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="action1"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="action1" name="action1" placeholder="An Action" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="bodypart"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="bodypart" name="bodypart" placeholder="A body part" type="text"
                                    required="required" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="liquid"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-glass"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="liquid" name="liquid" placeholder="A liquid" type="text" required="required"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="place"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input id="place" name="place" placeholder="A place" type="text" required="required"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="closeFirst" name="submit" type="submit" class="submit btn-lg modal-btn mt-5" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#formModalOutput" onClick="{handleDocSubmit.bind(this)}">View your story!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Form End  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->

    <!-- Output Modal Start -->
    <div class="modal fade text-center align-items-center" id="formModalOutput" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="formModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="formModalOutputTitle">This is your output modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="close-text text-dark font-weight-bold float-right">x</a>
                </div>
                <div id="modalOutputContent" class="modal-body p-5"><!-- Modal output content -->
                    <p class="modal-intro">This is your output modal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Output Modal End -->
```

also, here's my javascript:

```
// Create Variable //
var costumevar = document.getElementById('costume').value;
// Write on Modal //
function write(){
    document.getElementById('modalOutputContent').innerHTML = "Oh, hey there! Nice "+costumevar+" you got over there!";
}
```

Can anyone please help?

I am unable to use data-dismiss="modal" as it completely scraps the idea of fetching data input from the first modal.